# Is it dangerous to continue to remove a slightly punctured phone battery?

Tags: batteries, telephone, damage, replacement

I have been trying to replace the phone screen on a Galaxy S7, and therefore had to remove the battery in the process. While doing so, I saw a tiny spark and felt a weird smell. I can't see any damage on the battery, but obviously it is no longer safe to use, and I am going to have to replace it, and dispose of the old battery properly. My problem is: the battery is still glued to my phone. Is it dangerous to continue to remove the battery now, or should I just trash the entire phone? If not; is it safe to use a heat gun to loosen up the glue?

Also; could it be dangerous to leave it on the kitchen table over night? 
Should I wear gloves when doing this now?

I have looked for answers on the internet for over an hour now, but I still haven't found anything on removing an already damaged battery or the dangers of leaving it unattended.

Comment: Damaged batteries are bad, you could always try and discharge it at your own risk with a resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... had to remove the battery in the process.
>   While doing so, I saw a tiny spark and felt a weird smell. I can't see any damage on the battery, but obviously it is no longer safe to use, and I am going to have to replace it, and dispose of the old battery properly.

Given the above statements, your aims are removal of the battery without damage to
- yourself
- the phone

in that order.

Nothing is certain. You will probably be able to discharge the battery safely, but this is not 100% certain.

The phone's location during the removal process should be somewhere where a battery fire will not matter.

Discharging the battery fully, either using the phone or by other means, before attempting removal is safer than not doing so.
If you can turn the phone on then, as long as it is functioning normally, it will discharge the battery over the "standby period" or less.
If you can access the battery wires or terminals then you can discharge the battery using a resistor. This is a surer method but harder to do if inexperienced.

If it has a "flashlight" then this will usefully reduce discharge time.
The battery will still retain some energy when the phone decides that it is 'flat' but will be much less liable to cause damage.
(A 1500 mAh x 3.6V battery with 1% charge has about 150 Watt seconds of energy remaining. The same energy as is required to raise a 1 kg weight 15 metres - not to be treated too lightly).

> ... is it safe to use a heat gun to loosen up the glue?

Maybe, but **not wise**. Do not do unless essential AND you are willing to have the phone destroyed.
Even using the absolute minimum of temperature, the odds are the rise needed to be useful is above what the phone itself will withstand.

> Also; could it be dangerous to leave it on the kitchen table over night?

Yes - potentially so. As above, leave phone somewhere that a fire does not matter (except to the phone).

> Should I wear gloves when doing this now?

May help but adds fumble-fingeredness.
Probably good enough to use care, prompt action, eye protection, sensible clothes. LiIon batteries usually do not "explode" - they transition to a flaming heap - sometimes over a minute or so - or occasionally in seconds. I have NEVER had this happen but my all-care-no-responsibility comment is that I'd act as above with the awareness of the unlikely but possible worst case results.

---

Note the article cited by James Large in comments
[Toxic fluoride gas emissions from lithium-ion battery fires](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-09784-z). I'd be suitably wary of the fumes - but no more so than with fumes from many other electronic and chemical systems. ie aim to breath none, make it extremely unlikely that you'll get more than a whiff worst case, use of a fan or ventilator is liable to help. Note their notes on using water mist for extinguishing such fires. Water is not recommended as it reportedly may increase Lithium combustion rate and also the rate of HF production (but not the total HF produced).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That was really helpful. I'm glad the battery was already charged out before I did this :^)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like you shorted something. The phone may be broken. You probably didn't puncture the battery unless you jabbed into it hard with a tool, you would be able to see a puncture mark.

As far as safety: this is just my personal opinion, but I think it should be fine to work on. If you suspect that the battery IS damaged, then I would work on it outside. If the battery does get pierced, it will spray fire but I don't think the energy will be enough to burn you instantly, you'll probably just have to toss the phone into a safe place to let it burn out. Just be prepared to do that and you should be fine.

Edit: To answer your question about storage. Like I said it's probably ok, but you could put it somewhere fireproof just in case. Its very unlikely that anything will happen with the phone off and stationary, but it's not hard to just leave it on the stove or something so why not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Leaving it in the stove is a good idea. Upon further inspection there might be a tiny rift in the black cover on the battery. Also It seems like it is slightly bulging out. Does this change anything?

Comment: Slight bulging on old batteries is pretty common. I don't think it changes anything.

Comment: Where there is fire, there is smoke.  Some lithium batteries contain fluoride salts, and they can emit hydrogen fluoride gas when they burn.  Inhaling it can have long-lasting health consequences. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-09784-z

Comment: @jameslarge - I used your cited reference (with attribution) at the end of my answer.